# Is html_safe good practice when storing video embed links in text format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, embed

My app allows users to embed videos from popular sites like youtube, etc. I have a text_area_field to accept the embed code as a string and save to the database. I am doing some basic validation with a regular expression to filter certain parts of the embed code. Sample embed code from youtube:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/INx7B2yyD0g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When i display the video back to the user i do this in my view

<%= user.content.html_safe %>

**What i would like to know, is the following:**
1. Is is safe to call html_safe on user submitted data, what other options do i have
2. Is storing the embed code as a string type good practice
3. Are there are any loopholes for users to submit bad scripts
4. What can be done differently to prevent such attacks
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go the route of using something like the [sanitize gem](https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/) with a custom whitelist. But since it would have to accept things like `<iframes>` that could get tricky.

The safest bet would probably be to use an HTML parser like [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) to parse out the specific needed values and insert them into your own template for each service.

For your example embed code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/INx7B2yyD0g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You'd just need to grab something like:

```
{:with => 560, :height => 315, :youtube_id => 'INx7B2yyD0g'}
```

It's definitely more work since you'd have to have different parsers and templates for each different video service you supported. But it's the safest way I can think of to avoid malicious HTML injection.

Comment: thanks, i was thinking along the lines of nokogiri, but thought there might be another way.